# jQuery change image src based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of dynamically generated divs all with unique data-id's and several image icons contained within. When an Icon is clicked a box pops up allowing a selection dependent on the action chosen. This updates the database via ajax.

I need the first icon to change when the ajax reauest returns 3.

```
var ls="<div class='list_body'>
            <div class='lister1'>
                <img src='"+path+stat1+"' data-icon_no='1' data-status='"+split_stats[0]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
                <img src='"+path+stat2+"' data-icon_no='2' data-status='"+split_stats[1]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
                <img src='"+path+stat3+"' data-icon_no='3' data-status='"+split_stats[2]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
                <img src='"+path+stat4+"' data-icon_no='4' data-status='"+split_stats[3]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
                <img src='"+path+stat5+"' data-icon_no='5' data-status='"+split_stats[4]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
                <img src='"+path+stat6+"' data-icon_no='6' data-status='"+split_stats[5]+"' data-job_id='"+split_stats[18]+"' />
            </div>
            <div class='lister'>"+split_stats[6]+" "+split_stats[7]+" "+split_stats[8]+"<br />["+split_stats[13]+"]"+"</div>
            <div class='lister'>"+split_stats[14]+"</div>
            <div class='lister'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='lister_a'>View Appointment &amp; Actions</a></div>
        </div>";
```

(I have tried to space the code to make it more readable but basically this is just one line of many that is appended to the document)

My jQuery so far is...

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit_acc', function(){
        var selected=$('.conf_app').val();
        var agent=$('body').data('agent_id');

        if(selected==0)
        {
            alert("Please make a selection from the available options.");
            return;
        }

        var reason=$('.ag_com').val();
        var data="agent_id="+agent+"&selected="+selected+"&reason="+reason+"&job_id="+gl_job_id;
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"admin_includes/conf_job.php",
            data:data,
            context:gl_job_id,
            success:function(html){

                if(html=="3")
                {
 //this is where I can't get it to work......
                    $('.lister1[data-job_id="'+gl_job_id+'"'').find('img').eq(0).src("images/icons/start_green.png");

                }
            }
        })//end ajax

});
```

I am baiscally having trouble identifying the row where to change the image.

gl_job_id is a global variable that holds the job_id which is used as the identifier in data-job_id (does that make sense ??)..

Currently this is throwing an error on the selector line but obviously the syntax is totally wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong selector here:

```
$('.lister1[data-job_id="'+gl_job_id+'"'').find('img').eq(0).src("images/icons/start_green.png");
```

you trying to select `div` by `data-job_id`, also remove one `'` and add `]`

Something like this must be:

```
$('.lister1 [data-job_id="'+gl_job_id+'"]').attr('src', "images/icons/start_green.png");
```

this code select `div`, then find by `data-job_id` and set `src` attribute

Comment: This does not throw the errors but it does not update the first img icon in the row.

Comment: @Sideshow maybe problem in ajax result? or in `gl_job_id` because this is not a unique id. My selector works: http://jsfiddle.net/cGbtW/

Comment: I can see the logic of this but still cannot get the inage to update in my code...I'll keep slaving on :)

Comment: @Sideshow use `alert()` or `console.log()` to debug your params

Comment: gl_job_id works fine. I think it is more to do with selecting the right icon (in this case the first icon). lister1 is the class of the containing div whereas each icon has the data-job_id attribute in the img tag. I think it is a case of finding the icons with the  correct data-job_id and selecting the first one, then applting the cahnge of the image src...

Comment: $('.lister1').find('img[data-job_id="'+gl_job_id+'"]:first').attr('src', 'images/icons/start_green.png'); This seems to work for the first icon. Thanks for your help.